# Docker: Running Windows Console application - Failed to create system events window thread

Tags: docker, .net-core, containers, console-application

I am trying to run a windows console application (.net core) in a container. It is working fine on host but as soon as I run the docker container, it throws this **error**:

```
The type initializer for 'MyApp.Utility.SystemEventsHandler' threw an exception.
 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): Failed to create system events window thread.
   at Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.EnsureSystemEvents(Boolean requireHandle)
   at Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.add_SessionEnding(SessionEndingEventHandler value)
```

**Docker File**

```
# getting base image 
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:3.1

#  copy files 
COPY app/ app/

# set working directory
WORKDIR app

# entry point
#ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","MyApp.dll"]
```

Do I need to install something else too in the container ?

Comment: You are probably using a linux container and then try to access windows specifics APIs, which of course wont work in a linux environment.

Comment: @Henkolicious,   I am running this on windows.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that you are running the console app on a windows OS host with docker. The problem is that you are running a linux container (very slim version of a linux OS) and then trying to access windows specific APIs.

As the error states `Failed to create system events window thread.    at Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents...`

That is why the application is working just fine when you debug it on your windows OS host, but not in a linux container. You will get the same effect if you deploy it to a regular linux host or trying to run it in WSL for example.

One thing that might work is switching to a `windows container`, but I don't know how your code looks. To switch to windows container, *I think* you simply right click the system tray icon for docker desktop and swap. But I've never used windows containers, so I would not know.

[image: Switch to Windows containers....]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/building-net-docker-images?view=aspnetcore-5.0#run-in-a-windows-container

PS I hope you are not trying to run a GUI application in docker, that is not supported.

Comment: That is incorrect. I am running my application in a windows container.